# Error: 'lat' has incorrect length using the Thornthwaite function from the SPEI package

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the thornthwaite function from the SPEI package to calculate Pet from  monthly temperature and latitude data however I keep getting the error messsage

> Error: "lat" has incorrect length".

This is weird because the latitude and temperatue columns are the same length with no NA's. My data is latitudes for the UK at a 1km resolution.

```
Pet <- thornthwaite(data.frame$Tm, data.frame$lat, na.rm = FALSE)
```

Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: Please supply a sufficient sample of your data, e. g. by pasting the output of `dput(head(data.frame))`:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ; aside: naming your objects with names reserved for common functions like `data.frame` makes debugging more difficult.